# OpenMP и компилятор

Tags: openmp

Не могу никак запустить проект с OpenMp.
В Visual Studio выдает ошибку error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__You_must_link_with_Microsoft_OpenMP_library"

В Dev C++ же выдает вот такое : C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\main.o   main.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_sections'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\main.o   main.cpp:(.text+0x3af): undefined reference to`GOMP_sections_next'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\main.o   main.cpp:(.text+0x3c9): undefined reference to `GOMP_sections_end_nowait'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\main.o   main.cpp:(.text+0x3d3): undefined reference to`GOMP_sections_next'
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
25      C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Makefile.win recipe for target 'OPENMP.exe' failed

Не могу ничего сделать. Подскажите как быть ?

Comment: А вы lib-файлы в проект добаляли?

Comment: в студии - да. Скачал SDKs и линканул эту папку. В деве - нет. Вроде как там не нужно. Только -fopenmp добавил

Comment: А конкретно lib-файлы вы добавляли? Каталог с lib-файлами говорит где их искать, если указано имя файла. Все что там лежит не прилинкуется само :-)

Comment: Нет. Так не добавлял. Я по этому "гайду" делал все
http://iproc.ru/programming/openmp-visual-studio/

Comment: Попробуйте найти нужный lib и указать его в настройках проекта.

Comment: А я не могу найти нужный мне lib в файлах установленной сдк. Там попросту нет omp.lib